# Net::Whois::Raw behind a proxy

Tags: perl

I am using [`Net::Whois::Raw`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Whois::Raw) on two systems: one system without a proxy where it works well, the other system with a proxy, where it throws an error on `/lib/Net/Whois/Raw.pm` line 171. My code is like the below:

```
use Net::Whois::Raw;

my $host = shift;
$Net::Whois::Raw::CHECK_FAIL = 1;
$Net::Whois::Raw::OMIT_MSG = 1;

my $whois_raw = whois($host);

print $whois_raw;
```

Where the host is provided on the command line.

Could someone provide an example of how to configure this module to work with a proxy?

Comment: What error message are you getting exactly?

Comment: whois.crsnic.net: Bad file descriptor: whois.crsnic.net:43 at ... Net/Whois/Raw.pm line 309.

Comment: What kind of proxy? WHOIS isn't an HTTP-based protocol; it can't be used through an HTTP proxy.

Comment: it seems the second machine using 43 which is blocked by firewall do you know any web proxy which can be configured to work with Net::Whois::Raw or any other cpan module which using web proxy ?